# search for single meta_key with numeric array of meta values

Tags: search, post-meta

I was using a custom post let's say 'question' where user publishes the 'question' with a 'post meta' called 'course', in which multiple 'course names' stored as course id's(as a string separated with comma). I am writing a search functionality where user enters course name then by using that 'course name' I get the 'course id', My Question here is that how to search for my 'course id' with 'meta_query' called 'course' stored as a string? I am using WP_Query for this, below is my code:
While Storing:

```
  $course_registered = '2013,1919,1827'; // Saving Multiple Course names as Course ID's
  $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_status'   => 'draft', 
        'post_type' => "question"  // Use a custom post type if you want to
        );
  wp_insert_post($post);
  update_post_meta( $this->post_ID, 'inistitute_name', $institute_name );
  update_post_meta( $this->post_ID, 'course', $course_registered );
```

While searching query:

```
  if($_GET['tewa_search']!="") 
    {
       global $wpdb;
       $course_key = $_GET['tewa_search'];

       $query= "SELECT ID FROM `wp_posts` WHERE wp_posts.post_title LIKE '$course_key%' and wp_posts.post_type='courses'";
       $wp_query = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_N);
       if( ! empty($wp_query) ){    
          $keyword = $wp_query[0][0];   
       }
       else{
          $keyword = $_GET['tewa_search'];  
       }

       $keyword = $_GET['search_keyword'];
       $institute_name = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'inistitute_name', true);
       $status=array('publish','pending', 'draft');
       $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
       $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
         'post_type' => 'question',
         array("s" => $keyword),
         'meta_query' => array (
         'relation' => 'OR',
         array (
           'key' => 'course',
           'value' => $keyword, //$keyword = 1827 (getting course id based on user entered keyword)
           'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array (
            array (
              'key' => 'inistitute_name',
              'value' => array ($institute_name),
              'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' =>$paged,
    'post_status' => $status,
    'order' => 'DESC'
    ));
  }
```

Seriously It is driving me nuts, Please help me. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `array("s" => $keyword)` as it is search all post which contain `$keyword` value, what institute value  is about?  `multiple 'course names' stored as course id's(as a numeric array)` means?

Comment: @GovindKumar, I updated above code plz check it once. I am storing a numeric array values into post_meta of 'course' .

Comment: why you are passing `$keyword` to course meta_value,  does this variable contain course id or search query? also don't use `get_user_meta` to get post meta value of post use `get_post_meta` instead . your code is totally, there are many errors. i can help you edit question and write your proper requirement .

Comment: if user entered keyword is course name then I will get the corresponding course id and use it in 'course' post_meta or else if keyword is something else like 'post_title', 'post_content', etc. I am using WP_Query 's 's'=>$keyword for this.

Comment: An array is a php data structure, that value gets converted to a serialized string to get stored in the database. An `IN` comparison won't work to search within a string, it's looking for an exact match.

Comment: @Milo, That is why I am storing the numeric values as string separated with comma like this : $course_registered = '2013,1919,1827', plz see the above code.

Comment: You have a string then, not a numeric array. Same problem though, `IN` will never match your data saved in that format, you need a `LIKE` variant.

Comment: @Milo, I have tried that too I have put 'LIKE', '=' & 'IN' for 'compare' field, but no luck. Apart from that, Am trying just searching for only 'post_title' &  'post_content', for this Am using just "array('s'=>$keyword)" then it is working sometimes & sometimes not working.